# How take parameter from javascript in html

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose to have an array:

```
array: ['hi,'by','miao']
```

Suppose to pass this array to one html page and I want put the second element in my html code:

```
<input type="button" id='{array[1]}'>....
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I know Javascript and HTML, and nowhere have I seen the syntax `id='{array[1]}'` before. I know it is possible to set the id using jQuery, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you want the id to be literarily "{array[1]}", your code should work. But if you want that id to be "by", you'll have to actually set the id of the element: document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').id = array[1]; Basic html/javascript doesn't support syntax that will automatically fill values from javascript into html. You'd have to use a framework for that kind of coding.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a close quote after the hi:

```
array: ['hi','by','miao']
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's the missing quote, as @erognaut and @unenthusiasticuser have pointed out.

As far as I know, I don't think it's possible to inject JS variables into HTML like you're trying to do there. It is possible with PHP or a server-side language, though.

Or, like @jBot-42 said, you may want to change the `id` using JS or jQuery using a script, but not like that. For example:

```
<input type="button" data-id='array_elem' />

<script>
    var array = ['hi','by','miao'];
    // uses jQuery
    $("input[data-id='array_elem']").attr("id", array[1]);
</script>
```